# bouncy castle equivalent of openssl pkcs10 certificate signing command

Tags: java, openssl, bouncycastle, client-certificates, pkcs#10

I am trying to sign a pkcs10 request using bouncy castle in Java. The resulting cert will be used in a two-way ssl scenario. I've looked through and tried many of the examples on this and other sites, but I always end up get the following when trying to connect my client to the server:

--java--

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: 
I/O error on GET request for "https://localhost:8443/resources/1":
Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown;
nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
```

--openssl--

```
$ openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443 -CAfile ca.crt -cert client.crt -key client.key -pass pass:password -showcerts
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 /C=xx/ST=xx/L=xx/O=xxxx/OU=xxxx/CN=xxxx/emailAddress=xxxx@xxxx.com
verify return:1
depth=0 /C=xx/ST=xx/L=xx/O=xxxx/OU=xxxx/CN=localhost/emailAddress=xxxx@xxxx.com
verify return:1
76234:error:14094416:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert certificate unknown:
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098
-59.40.2/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1145:SSL alert number 46
76234:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-59.40.2/src/ssl/s23_lib.c:185:
```

I've made many attempts with bouncy castle, but here is one attempt just as an example:

```
public Certificate signCertificateSigningRequest(PKCS10CertificationRequest certificationRequest,
        Certificate caCertificate, PrivateKey caPrivateKey) throws Exception {
    X500Name issuer = getX500Name("xxxx");
    Calendar notBefore = Calendar.getInstance();
    notBefore.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
    Calendar notAfter = Calendar.getInstance();
    notAfter.add(Calendar.YEAR, 3);
    X509v3CertificateBuilder certGen = new X509v3CertificateBuilder(
        issuer,
        BigInteger.valueOf(3),
        notBefore.getTime(),
        notAfter.getTime(),
        certificationRequest.getSubject(),
        certificationRequest.getSubjectPublicKeyInfo()
    );
    X509CertificateHolder certHolder = certGen
        .build(new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256withRSA").setProvider("BC").build(caPrivateKey));
    X509Certificate certificate = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC").getCertificate(certHolder);
    return certificate;
}
```

What I would like is the bouncy castle equivalent of the following openssl command which I know works:

```
$ openssl \
x509 \
-req \
-in client.csr \
-CA ca.crt \
-CAkey ca.key \
-passin pass:password \
-CAcreateserial \
-sha256 \
-out client.crt \
-days 3650
```

This has been driving me nuts. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer here: [X509 certificate signed with bouncy castle is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38634897/x509-certificate-signed-with-bouncy-castle-is-not-valid?rq=1)

The answer had to do with the issuer given to the X509v3CertificateBuilder. The issuer return by getX500Name("xxxx") should be identical to the one that generated the cert, but I guess it isn't. I had to change:

```
X500Name issuer = getX500Name("xxxx");
```

to:

```
X500Name issuer = X500Name.getInstance(((X509Certificate)caCertificate).getSubjectX500Principal().getEncoded());
```

and now it works fine.